# Read HURDAT2 data via Tropycal package

Tags: python, python-3.x, weather

I can't seem to understand why the Tropycal package can't read in HURDAT 2 data with Python 3.10.

My errors:

```
--> Starting to read in HURDAT2 data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jroth\Desktop\Workspace\Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    hurdat_atl = tracks.TrackDataset(basin='north_atlantic',source='hurdat',include_btk=False)
  File "C:\Users\jroth\AppData\Local\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\tropycal\tracks\dataset.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.__read_hurdat()
  File "C:\Users\jroth\AppData\Local\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\tropycal\tracks\dataset.py", line 367, in __read_hurdat
    date = dt.strptime(yyyymmdd+hhmm,'%Y%m%d%H%M')
  File "C:\Users\jroth\AppData\Local\anaconda4\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\jroth\AppData\Local\anaconda4\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '999-999' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M'
```

Working with Tropycal, the initial code is very simple. But when reading into the package database it massively errors out.

```
import tropycal.tracks as tracks
basin = tracks.TrackDataset(basin='north_atlantic',source='hurdat',include_btk=False)
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the current version and previous version.

I am expecting the output to be the following:

```
--> Starting to read in HURDAT2 data
--> Completed reading in HURDAT2 data (X.XX seconds)
```

Comment: Because, as the error message says, there is "999-999" in your data where it does not belong.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the problem with that is that's how HURDAT2 database is written. https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/hurdat2.html